# Car wheel's "slip ratio" equation for game

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Some of you may know about slip ratio. It is specific ratio that kind of depends on wheel rotation speed, radius etc. and affects friction. Car has the most friction at around 0.05-0.1 slip ratio (coefficient of friction is aroundaround 85-95% of it's value), no friction at 0.0 slip ratio and medium friction at 0.3-1.0 slip ratio (c.f. is around 50-60% of it's value).

It's easy explained in this graph:

[image: Slip Ratio Curve]

However, I don't know how to calculate slip ratio (the value on X axis of graph). I want it, though, to be in 0.0-1.0 float value instead of 0-100 integer value in %. I have access to such things as wheel rotation speed, car speed etc. I would be really happy if you told me how to calculate the slip value.

Comment: Is the definition in Wikipedia without making it a percentage not good enough?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ratio

Comment: @Farcher OK! Once I subtract 1, it seems to be around the area of -0.9...-1.1, which is wrong. So I decided to not to subtract it. However, it seams to not to apply to the friction correctly... IDK if my friction application is wrong.

Comment: OK! It is not kinda working as supposed. Maybe it won't work like that in games? Do you know how to calculate wheel angular velocity from the torque that receives from differential and wheel's radius?