# Slip definition that works in game

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_(vehicle_dynamics)) gives us the following 2 equations: $$\%_{slip} = \frac{\omega r - v}{|v|} * 100$$
(The use of $v$ modulus makes it work in all directions. It is multiplied by 100 to get the percentage) and
$$\alpha = \arctan\frac{v_y}{|v_x|}.$$
Those formulas does work well at high car speed. When plugged into Pacejka equations, they result in pretty realistic car behavior. However, once the speed becomes low, it starts to diverge(not even talking about 0 speed where it's $\infty$). And when diverging, it becomes unstable. At low speeds it can even make the wheels, for example, to start to turn in the opposite direction, or car to be shaking from left to right. This is because this slip definition is not proper at low speeds. I'm looking for a better collection of equations that would work well at any car's speed. It should still support the Pacejka formula (and use the same values).

Comment: The minimum value of $-1$, means the tires are not rotating. Perhaps you've mistaken this for rotating backwards?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  Unless I am mistaken, these equations quantify how much slip is occurring in a given situation.  They do not predict how much slip will occur.  Linked Q : Car wheel's "slip ratio" equation for game, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235853.

Comment: No, you don't get the problem. The problem is that those equations are unstable and broken at low speeds. And I'm looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Belive it or not, but I solved it in very funny and simple method. I made even lighter function, but it works better. Instead of using slip ratio percentage, I use slipping speed(non %, non ratio - a linear slip that depends on speed) and it works like a charm.

$V_{slip} = \omega r - V_{longitudal}$

Where:
$V_{slip}$ - wheel longitudal speed
$\omega$ - wheel angular velocity
$r$ - wheel radius
$V_{longitudal}$ - wheel longitudal tangential speed

Belive me or not, but this works amazingly perfect. THe best way to test it was for free rolling wheels using friction force as resistance torque. And they really become perfect free-rolling wheels.